I try to change the background color of topappbar
I am new to kivymd, using version 2.0.1dev0 and I want to apply TopAppBar but when I try to change the background color it just doesn't work and only shows white color. This is my code
<MainScreen>:
    MDScreen:
        MDNavigationLayout:
            MDScreenManager:
                MDScreen:
                    name: "main_screen"
                    
                    MDTopAppBar:
                        type: "small"
                        md_bg_color: 0.2,0.4,0.8,1                    

                        MDTopAppBarLeadingButtonContainer:

                            MDActionTopAppBarButton:
                                icon: "menu"

                        MDTopAppBarTitle:
                            text: "Página Principal"

                        MDTopAppBarTrailingButtonContainer:

                            MDActionTopAppBarButton:
                                icon: "dots-vertical"

Note: The code is executed and manages to display the window with the bar.
I tried changing the md_bg_color option on different lines but it doesn't work, I also read the kivy documentation but it doesn't mention color so I'm afraid there is no such option. I hope someone has a solution.
Thank you so much.

Welcome to stackoverflow! I can reproduce the malfunction on my machine with version 2.0.1dev0. With version 1.2.0 it works as intended, so I guess it is a bug on kivymd's side. You could try to seek guidance via their github issues.
